# Unity - Cannot generate random number within a class construct

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, random, construct

I have been trying to create my own class using C# in Unity but I've come across a small issue. Within my **PlayerClass construct** I want to generate a string of **six random numbers** using Random.Range (0, 9) use as a reference number. Currently, the line of code I am using to do this, looks like this:

```
refNum = Random.Range (0, 9) + Random.Range (0, 9) + Random.Range (0, 9) + Random.Range (0, 9) + Random.Range (0, 9) + Random.Range (0, 9);
```

I have created the variable **refNum** outside of the construct at the top of the class. Every time I run my game I get an error saying I cannot generate random numbers from within a class construct. Does anybody know a way around this?

Many Thanks,

Tommy

Comment: Not really a solution, but are you just summing 6 random numbers? As the result, you will have max 2 digit number. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36104497/384674 also ;-)

Comment: Is this a monobehavior attached to an object? If so, use `Start()` or `Awake()` instead.

Comment: @Betlista six dice rolled and summed do not have a uniform distribution. This may be important for the asker.

Comment: I have tried using both Start and Awake but, because the script is not attached to an object, it still didn't work. @Draco18s

Comment: Is there any way I could call Start or Awake from the construct? @Draco18s

Comment: @TommyEaves No. MonoBehaviours are explicitly constructed through reflection magic and have limitations placed on them for a reason.

Comment: @Draco18s My point was, that he mentioned he wanted to "generate a string of six random numbers", instead of that just summing 6 random numbers (which won't result in 6 characters long string)...

Comment: @Betlista Ah, yes, if it is supposed to be a *string* then it's definitely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a string containing six random digits (0-9) you need first be sure of which `Random` class you want to use (the one from `UnityEngine` or from `System`). If you are using the one from `UnityEngine`, you should do something like this:

```
string randomString = Random.Range(0, 9).ToString() + Random.Range(0, 9).ToString() + Random.Range(0, 9).ToString() + Random.Range(0, 9).ToString() + Random.Range(0, 9).ToString() + Random.Range(0, 9).ToString();
```

Or perhaps a more elegant way to do it:

```
string randomString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        randomString += Random.Range(0, 9).ToString();
```

Comment: I have made a separate function within my PlayerClass which holds your second way of generating a random number. It works but I cannot call it through my constructor. Is there anyway that I can call this function each time I create a new variable of type PlayerClass from any other script?

Comment: I have reproduced what you described without any errors. Have you ensured that you are declaring `using UnityEngine;` in the file that you are writing your `PlayerClass`?

Comment: Yes I am definitely using UnityEngine

Comment: Could you include the error log in your question? It could be helpful

Comment: Never mind. I used this method then just called the function from the script where I was creating the new variable. Thank you!